# Unity - PoolingSystem failing to instantiate

Tags: unity

I am wanting to spawn monsters into my scene in Unity. I was told to use a Pooling System, so I got the free one Unity offers in the Asset store. I have followed the little documentation that there is, and am encountering an error. I do not know if I am just missing something but I am getting an object reference not set error.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PoolingSystem.InstantiateAPS (System.String itemType) (at Assets/Advanced Pooling     System/PoolingSystem.cs:104)
MobSpawner.Start () (at Assets/_Scripts/MobSpawner.cs:16)
```

It throws this on the following code:

```
private PoolingSystem poolingSystem;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    poolingSystem = PoolingSystem.Instance;

    poolingSystem.InstantiateAPS("Resources/EnemyPrefabs/Skeleton");
}
```

Could someone please guide me in the right direction or tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: I suspect you're mismatching the parameter on the InstantiateAPS() method. It may take a typeof(Skeleton) instead of the path to the resource. Look again at the documentation for that method. Also, check youtube. A lot of creators of assets like that have a video tutorial they put up

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source code, and it looks like InstantiateAPS requires the Prefab name as a parameter.

```
poolingSystem.InstantiateAPS("Skeleton");
```

This should probably work, so as long as you actually have a Skeleton prefab in your Resources folder.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, and it didnt work

Comment: Try instantiateAPS("EnemyPrefabs/Skeleton");   instead

Comment: Nah, ive tried all of the above, which is why I resorted to posting here. It says it takes a string itemType, which probably wouldnt be the prefab name? Idk its weird

Comment: yeah, if you look at the source code, it is being used like this:   

if(poolingItems[i].prefab.name == itemType)

And it then returns the Pooled item.  Make sure do in fact have a Pooled prefab, otherwise, I would assume this list would be empty.


Source here https://github.com/6ameDev/Advanced-Pooling-System/blob/master/Advanced%20Pooling%20System/PoolingSystem.cs

Comment: Omg yes this makes so much sense